# Stylus Error Reporting When Used As Express Middleware

Tags: debugging, express, stylus, error-reporting

I have used [express-generator](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html) to roll an app with [Stylus](http://stylus-lang.com/)

```
express --view=pug --css=stylus appdir
```

, want to know if there's a way to surface [Stylus' error reporting](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/error-reporting.html) when
running the application (`npm run start:dev`) and, if so, how to set that
up.

I know I can see this output by directly hitting [the Stylus executable](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/executable.html).
However, I'd rather not do the extra step if Express is getting that info
from Stylus under the hood or something more convenient like that already.

I want to be able to run my dev script (which uses nodemon), make some
breaking change (invalid syntax of whatever) to one of the projects
`*.styl`, and see the errors from Stylus somewhere. Currently the only
indication of bad Stylus files is that, on page reload, the server reports
`500` for `appdir/public/stylesheets/style.css`.